# Read two csv files simultaneously and use variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to read two csv files at the same time and use variables from each of the multiple columns. I've tried everything and searched all over SO, but no luck.
Here's my poor code:

```
with open("test1.csv","r",encoding="utf-8") as f, open("test2.csv","r",encoding="utf-8") as g:
fieldnames = ['username', 'password']
fieldnames2 = ['title', 'afflink']
rdr1 = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
rdr2 = csv.DictReader(g, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames2)

for row in rdr1:
    for row in rdr2:
        print(username, title)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Could you please include examples of your csv files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nested loops probably don't do what you want, though you have not actually told us anything about what you want. The inner loop will consume all the data in the second file and then proceed to read the second line of the first file, but then you can't loop over the second file again (unless you close and reopen and start over from the beginning). Probably you want to read one line from each at a time.

```
with open("test1.csv","r",encoding="utf-8") as f, open("test2.csv","r",encoding="utf-8") as g:
    # Fixed broken indentation here
    fieldnames = ['username', 'password']
    fieldnames2 = ['title', 'afflink']
    rdr1 = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    rdr2 = csv.DictReader(g, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames2)

    for d1, d2 in zip(rdr1, rdr2):
        print(d1['username'], d2['title'])
```

If your real-life loop is more complex than this, perhaps combine the dictionaries with something like `d1.update(d2)`. The main beef here is the observation that the DictReader objects return dictionaries (you have to use `dict['key']`, not `key` to retrieve the value for `key`) and that you can use `zip` to loop over pairs of values.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, it works so far. But how to get values from both (or more) columns of each file? Because I tried with zip before and it always throws "Not enough values to unpack,..." error.

Comment: If you `zip` two lists and loop over the result, you get two values on each iteration, in this case with each containing a dictionary which holds a row from each file. I'm guessing you tried to access individual fields within those dicts somehow. Without access to the broken code, I can obviously only speculate.

Comment: Well, I tried adding a row like this:     for d1, d2, d3 in zip(rdr1, rdr2):
        print(d1['username'], d2['title'], d3['afflink']) - but this obviously didn't work. How can I read all columns in these 2 files?

Comment: Again, you don't have three things coming out of `zip`, so it's not clear what you expect that to do. The `afflink` field comes from `rdr2`; so `for d1, d2 in zip(rdr1, rdr2): print(d1['username'], d2['title'], d2['afflink'])`

Comment: Ugh, I'm an idiot. Of course, now it works! Thanks a lot for the help:)